# Unable to write to mysql database using PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I have an Excel file that gets data from WebQuery and i want to read the data, insert into mySQL database. Unable to write to mysql database using following code. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";$db_user = "root";$db_pass = "";$db_name ="report";$db_table = "test";
require '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('Refreshables.xlsx');
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
{
$worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
$highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) 
{
    $val=array();
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) 
    {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val[] = $cell->getValue();
    }
        $sql = "insert into 'test' (AppName, Device_Full_Name, App_Type, Carrier, Language, Version, Status, Platform, Project_Type, Base_Device, Build_Type, Project_ID) values('".$val[0]."', '".$val[1]."', '".$val[2]."','".$val[3]."', '".$val[4]."', '".$val[5]."','".$val[6]."', '".$val[7]."', '".$val[8]."','".$val[9]."', '".$val[10]."', '".$val[11]."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
} 
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong where? Do the queries succeed? (Use `mysql_error` to find out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$sql = "insert into 'test' (AppName,...
                    ^    ^ don't use quotes in table or column names
```

to

```
$sql = "insert into `test` (AppName,...
```

or even without back ticks

```
$sql = "insert into test (AppName,...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :).
Data is being inserted but is incomplete. i have 6 sheets where  sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 data is inserted correctly. last row of Sheets 4,5,6 is skipped for some reason. Can any one help?